# Understanding Mesh Analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: Mesh Analysis Circuit]

Using Multisim, I was able to calculate these current values, however I can't seem to understand their correlation with the individual mesh loop current values I calculated using matrices in MATLAB.

In my calculations, i1 is 3A, i2 is 2A, and i3 is 4A. How would I show that the data in this model supports these calculations?

Comment: The values you got seems wrong. It would be helpful if you can post the set of equations you used to calculate.

Comment: The currents in your schematic look correct. How did you get \$I_1 = 3A\$?

Answer (score 1):

Your mesh currents are wrong. These are the correct equations:

$$\begin{align}
I_1R_1+(I_1-I_3)R_3+(I_1-I_2)R_2&=0\\
(I_2-I_1)R_2+(I_2-I_3)R_4&=15V\\
(I_3-I_2)R_4+(I_3-I_1)R_3&=21V
\end{align}$$

Solving this system gives the following mesh currents:

$$\begin{align}
I_1&=18.000\,A\\
I_2&=21.545\,A\\
I_3&=20.818\,A
\end{align}$$

All currents in the network can be calculated from these mesh currents, and the results correspond to the ones obtained by Multisim, e.g. the current through \$R_2\$ is \$I_2-I_1=3.5455\,A\$.